# Time complexity of reursion method that reverses array

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I was working through a problem where I have to reverse the integers in an array recursively.

```
public int[] reverse(int[] A, int i){
    if(i = A){
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it's O(n/2) also, and you remove the constant of "1/2" to get O(n).

Comment: Each step if you break it down enough is always going to be 1.  It's the fact that you always take n/2 of them (it grows with n) that makes it O(n).

Answer (score 1):

It is "O(n/2)" but [since the multiplication of a constant for big O notation doesn't affect the big O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Properties), it is O(n).

Comment: well, that's short and true, I will upvote because you used less words than me haha

Answer (score 1):

The big O is about scale/magnitude, so O(n/2) == O(n) (read: order of n).

Each time the method is invoked it runs in constant time (because it's doing constant number of actions) so each time the method runs it runs in O(1), BUT we measure the total order of execution of the program, and since calling the method with `n > 1` starts a set of recursive calls, we say that the total execution of the program is in order of n => O(n)

Comment: well, here is an example of an expert answer, it's a plus one

Answer (score 1):

your algo is O(N) because O(N) describes an algorithm whose performance will grow linearly and in direct proportion to the size of the input data set, in your case, besides you divide by 2 the size, if you have an array of n elems, it will take n/2, if you have n+500 elemens, it will takes n+500/2, it means, the /2 is constant, and the algo will grow linearly. Meaning it depends directly of how long is N.